# iPhone app crash randomly when coming out of background

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, multitasking

I have an iPhone app which on very rare occasion will crash immediately while coming out of background from multitasking. No code is being run - the app will just crash immediately at this line in my main.m file:

`int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

Xcode tells me, "Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"."

Does anyone know as to why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information it is difficult to say what is happening here.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens when you try to access some invalid memory. This usually comes about because of overreleasing or underretaining an object.

Refresh your mind with the Cocoa Memory Management guide and check out these pages on CocoaDev

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingTechniques

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

You'll find a lot of techniques there to help you track down things like EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

The NSZombileEnabled article also contains a pretty good template for a .gdbinit file, which will setup a load of global breakpoints and set some environment variables whenever GDB is run. I find it very very useful.

So when you have these breakpoints in place and NSZombieEnabled set to YES, you won't see EXC_BAD_ACCESS, instead you'll get a breakpoint where the bad access would normally have occurred and a log message along the lines of "release sent to a deallocated instance" or something similar. That should pinpoint where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jasarien, but I do have NSZombieEnabled on my target, however there is still no useful information logged to the console.

Comment: Is there anything noticeable in the stack trace? Could you post the stack trace in your question?

Comment: I took a closer look at the stack, and `-[CLLocationManager onClientEvent]` is getting called twice before I get a nice objc-msgSend. I do have two CLLocationManagers running in my app, but I'm calling `-stopUpdatingLocation` on them when the app goes into the background. Does this mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time, but I did some digging and realised that I was missing an important call. I was forgetting to call the following in my view controller which had a CLLocationManager.

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    myLocationManager.delegate = nil;
    [myLocationManager release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thanks for your help, Jasarien.